# Automatically load a class & function in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have this code:

```
public function checkIfLogged(){
    if($this->router->class != 'common/login'){
        if(!$this->session->userdata('admin_id')){
            redirect('common/login');
        }
    }
}
```

It basically checks whether a user is logged into the admin panel.

Is there any way I can get this function to load automatically in each controller (apart from the login controller)?

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put this in the `My_Controller` class and in the `constructor` of My_Controller call this

```
Class My_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
$this->checkIfLogged();
}
public function checkIfLogged(){
if($this->router->class != 'common/login'){
    if(!$this->session->userdata('admin_id')){
        redirect('common/login');
    }
}
}

}
```

Every controller extends the My_Controller therefore `checkIfLogged` will call at each request

Comment: MY_Controller must extend CI_Controller. Also, beware that this code leads to an infinite loop, unless "common" doesn't extend MY_Controller: otherwise, you would be continuosly redirected

Comment: That's why I have the if statement, so that the if the controller is "common/login" then the redirect is prevented.

Comment: @dianuj: you forgot `parent::__construct();` inside `__construct()` method on the first line. [It's a must](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html).

Comment: @machineaddict it was not a copy paste :) i have wrote a dummy code just to make an idea and i am sure Peter is also takes my idea  not copy my code :)